# Cordova Crosswalk plugin not working (`cordova-plugin-crosswalk-webview`)

Tags: android, cordova, chromium, chromium-embedded, crosswalk

I am supporting a legacy application which uses crosswalk (https://github.com/crosswalk-project/cordova-plugin-crosswalk-webview) which has unfortunately been deprecated.

What we're seeing is that our styling is not coming through as expected. What Crosswalk is supposed to do is embed a chromium browser in the Cordova app so that all styling that occurs in the shimmed react application can target the Chromium browser. This tells me that Crosswalk is not getting loaded correctly.

This is what I have in my `config.xml` file (as it pertains to Crosswalk):

```
<preference name="xwalkVersion" value="23+" />
<preference name="xwalkLiteVersion" value="xwalk_core_library_canary:17+" />
<preference name="xwalkCommandLine" value="--disable-pull-to-refresh-effect" />
<preference name="xwalkMode" value="embedded" />
<preference name="xwalkMultipleApk" value="false" />

 <plugin name="cordova-plugin-crosswalk-webview" spec="^2.4.0">
        <variable name="XWALK_VERSION" value="23+" />
        <variable name="XWALK_LITEVERSION" value="xwalk_core_library_canary:17+" />
        <variable name="XWALK_COMMANDLINE" value="--disable-pull-to-refresh-effect" />
        <variable name="XWALK_MODE" value="embedded" />
        <variable name="XWALK_MULTIPLEAPK" value="false" />
  </plugin>
```

The commands that I use to get it to run are the following:

`cordova prepare` and `cordova run android` (I've attempted to run this on a simulator and on a connected device and the result is the same; the styling is incorrect).

A couple of notes. First, I am not sure what the difference is between the preferences and the variable names in the config file - the variable names are added in as shown above when I run `cordova plugins add cordova-plugin-crosswalk-webview`, but they do not appear to work unless the preferences are also specified (I am not sure why). Secondly, preference `xwalkMultipleApk` seems to be need to be set to false, OR, the armv7 apk needs to be used as there are architecture incompatibility issues with differing apk versions of Crosswalk.

Finally, to make sure that this build is completely clean and I run the latest `config.xml` file I run the following commands:

- `cordova clean`
- `cordova platforms rm android`
- `cordova prepare`
- `cordova platforms add android`
- `cordova run android`

I am not an expert in cordova, so please let me know if my build steps are not in the right order, although they appear to be to me.

Any help would be appreciated - my colleague and I have tried multiple approaches that are similar to the above without much success. If there is a newer, non-deprecated shim for a chromium browser that is an alternative to Crosswalk please let me know! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Check your plugin folder and see if it is installed.

Comment: Yes, it is installed in `cordova/plugins/cordova-plugin-crosswalk-webview` and `platforms/android/cordova-plugin-crosswalk-webview`

Comment: do cordova build android before the cordova run android and see if you get any errors.

Answer (score 0):

Place something in your JS that can verify the user-agent.  It is hard to tell what is going on here otherwise.

What is the specific need for crosswalk? Are you supporting older Android devices?